Индексация атрибутов внутри хеш-таблиц MongoDB
В монго хранятся документы со следующей структурой данных
{
    "_id": <object_id>,
    "items": {
        <id_1>: {"id": <id_1>, "value": 10},
        <id_2>: {"id": <id_2>, "value": 20},
        <id_3>: {"id": <id_3>, "value": 30}
    }
}

Нужно искать документы с определёнными value. Для ускорения поиска нужно индексировать value. Возможно ли это сделать, если items хеш-таблица?
Понимаю, что если items изменить на массив, то проблем не будет, но имею что имею.
Нужна помощь знатоков. Заранее спасибо!
